# lock the rows until next select postgres

Tags: postgresql, select, locking

Is there a way in postgres to lock the rows until the next select query execution from the same system.And one more thing is ***there will be no update process on locked rows.*** 
scenario is something like this

If the table1 contains data like

```
id |    txt
-------------------
1 |    World 
2 |    Text
3 |    Crawler
4 |    Solution
5 |    Nation
6 |    Under
7 |    Padding
8 |    Settle
9 |    Begin
10 |    Large
11 |    Someone
12 |    Dance
```

If sys1 executes

```
select * from table1 order by id limit 5;
```

then it should lock row from id 1 to 5 for other system which are executing select statement concurrently.

Later if sys1 again execute another select  query like

```
select * from table1 where id>10 order by id limit 5;
```

then pereviously locked rows should be released.

Comment: A design that needs to prevent reading of valid data that are not going to be updated probably has some design flaw. I'd try to rethink the process so that it doesn't need this bizarre behavior.

Comment: @9000 The process is like. A table called english_all contains huge list of words which are just words without any spell check.  Next these words should be fetched to different  system as I mention above. Then each user will sort the words it by just checking spell and store the word into another table like if it starts with a then table_a, if it is b then table_b and so on. I think this clarifies why I need locking mechanism so that same words would not processed by diffrent users.

Comment: Instead of `table_a`,... `table_z` I'd humbly suggest to `create index by_first_letter on table1(substring(txt from 1 to 1))` and make sure your "select by first letter" uses the same expression.

Comment: @9000 can you suggest any book or link which covers the advantages of  index by_first_letter implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible. You cannot block a read only access to a table (unless that select is done `FOR UPDATE`)

As far as I can tell, the only chance you have is to use the `pg_advisory_lock()` function. 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS

But this requires a "manual" release of the locks obtained through it. You won't get an automatic unlocking with that.

To lock the rows you would need something like this:

```
select pg_advisory_lock(id), * 
from 
( 
  select * table1 order by id limit 5
) t
```

(Note the use of the derived table for the LIMIT part. See the manual link I posted for an explanation)

Then you need to store the retrieved IDs and later call `pg_advisory_unlock()` for each ID.

If each process is always releasing **all** IDs at once, you could simply use `pg_advisory_unlock_all()` instead. Then you will not need to store the retrieved IDs.

Note that this will **not** prevent others from reading the rows using "normal" selects. It will only work if every process that accesses that table uses the same pattern of obtaining the locks.

Comment: @ahwnn Excellent, manual locking and unlocking wont be any problem for me.The link is useful for the required solution but I don't find anything about unlocking can be done by the same system as one which locks it,especially pg_advisory_unlock_all.If it works I will call that before calling pg_try_advisory_lock.

Comment: @ahwnn "select * from table1 where pg_try_advisory_lock(id) order by id limit 5;" this worked and locks the rows from sys1 and sys2 is not getting that rows.But I couldn't unlock the rows by pg_advisory_unlock_all() from sys1.But when browser tab(opera and mozilla) is closed it is releasing the locked rows. If I make pg_advisory_unlock_all() before selecting the rows ie in the beginging of post process in php will it unlock the rows previously locked.

Comment: Just a warning: if you combine this with database transactions, things can get a little funky. For example, if thread A acquires this lock in a transaction and thread B comes along to acquire the same lock, when A finally lets go (after committing the transaction) thread B gets the data from before thread A's transaction. The issue is the "SELECT pg_advisory_lock(id), *" syntax where you're trying to grab the lock and the data at the same time. Much safer to keep it as two calls. Select the lock, then in another query select the data. (Postgres 9.1 here, not sure about other versions.)

Comment: a question, does `select for update` locks the row just for the select statement or batch? or session? what if it's inside a function? would you check my question too sir? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694382/how-to-lock-a-row-during-a-function-call-in-pgsql?noredirect=1#comment41984591_26694382

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you really have a transaction which transcends the borders of your database, and all the change happens in an another system.

My idea is `select ... for update no wait` to lock the relevant rows, then offload the data into another system, then `rollback` to unlock the rows. No two `select ... for update` queries will select the same row, and the second `select` will fail immediately rather than wait and proceed.

But you don't seem to mark offloaded records in any way; I don't see why two *non-consecutive* selects won't happily select overlapping range. So I'd still `update` the records with a flag and/or a target user name and would only select records with the flag unset.

Comment: (1) for select...for update to work properly is it should be in the transaction compulsorily. I executed two different queries in  pgadmin's two query panel, but getting same rows.
(2) once the rows are selected should I have to apply update query to row compulsorily to unlock the row.

Comment: (1) You have to `begin transaction` for this to work, and run two different sessions (I used 2 instances of `psql`), then it works as advertised. (2) No, you don't have to actually update anything; you can `rollback` right after `select for update` just fine. No `update` or `select for update` will touch these rows until `rollback` or `commit` is issued.

Comment: Within transaction it works fine.But problem is with rollback now.Php file do_search.php is for query execution which calls the function get_all_words function and locks the rows using for update in transaction and echos the result to get_words.php(this file is one which calls the do_search.php though ajax). Now until all the fetched words are processed it should not be unlocked.Then where should I put rollback or is there a way to get transaction id and rollback that transaction after all words are processed.

Comment: If you can't fit the entire action into one transaction, you'll need to go for explicit, "hand-made" locking. (With pooled connections, you'll not even be able to rollback as you may get different connection the next page load.) This returns us to the idea of a flag in each row that you update every time you 'lock' your rows for operation, and then update (reset) again once you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both **select...for update** and **pg_try_advisory_lock** and managed to get near my requirement.

```
/*rows are locking but limit is the problem*/
select * from table1 where  pg_try_advisory_lock( id) limit 5;
.
.
$_SESSION['rows'] = $rowcount; // no of row to process
.
.
/*afer each process of word*/
$_SESSION['rows'] -=1;
.
.
/*and finally unlock locked rows*/
if ($_SESSION['rows']===0)
select pg_advisory_unlock_all() from table1
```

But there are two problem in this
1. As Limit will apply before lock, every time the same rows are trying to lock in different instance.
2. Not sure whether pg_advisory_unlock_all will unlock the rows locked by current instance or all the instance.